# drag and drop div onto div

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am not sure how to ask this question, but I'll try my best.

I am coding a website, and I have a list of div's that are generated with php. There is another div on the side. The idea is, when you drag one of the divs in the list onto the other div, it will do something with the class of the div in the list.

The HTML code for one of the divs in the list:

```
<div style='width:100px' class='div1' draggable='true'>
[content]
</div>
```

The HTML code for the div you drop it into:

```
<div class="dropzone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="padding: 10px; border-width: 2px; border-style: dashed; width: 100px; height: 210px; float: right;">
[content]
</div>
```

The idea is, when you drag "div1" into "dropzone", dropzone will run a javascript function with "div1" as a variable.
Is there a way to do this in javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: check out [jquery UI Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/)

Comment: You can watch for two events, the mouseup and mousedown events. If you want the draggable div to move, you'll have to write javascript to do so or use external code (usually in the form of plugins for major javascript libraries like jQuery). The basic idea is to use the mousedown, mousemove, and mouseup events to keep track of where the mouse started, where it is after a move, and where it ended up and then move the clicked object accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get idea from this site :

> http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/
>
> http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp